# Typescript Iterate using map and get key, value and delete item using index

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider I've this:

```
let users = {
    "user1": { "fname" : "fname1", "lname" : "lname1"},
    "user2": { "fname" : "fname2", "lname" : "lname2"},
    "user3": { "fname" : "fname3", "lname" : "lname3"}
 };
```

**Problem 1:**

I want to iterate over it, somewhat like this(I need both key and value):

```
users.map(function(key, value) {
       //use key,value here...
   }
}
```

**Problem 2:**

And I want to remove item from "users" maybe like:

```
users.filter(index => index !== i) //this will remove item at i-th index
```

How to perform this in typescript? Or are there any other better solutions...

Comment: problem 1: `Object.entries(users).forEach(([key, value]) => { console.log(key, value); })`

Comment: problem 2: `delete users.user2;`  there is no index in an object..  But you could maybe use a `Object.keys` to get an index, and then delete the key.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a TypeScript-specific problem, but more a JavaScript one.

When you want to iterate through an object keys, you can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) that serves this purpose.

```
Object.keys(users).map(key =>
  // Do something with
  users[key]
)
```